# Object Literal instead of switch

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to use object literal instead of switch statement, but i got this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ apple: string[]; orange: string[]; watermelon: string[]; default: void; }'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ apple: string[]; orange: string[]; watermelon: string[]; default: void;}' ts(7053)*

**SWITCH STATEMENT**

```
const fruits = (fruit: string): string[] => {
    switch (fruit) {
      case 'apple': {
        return state.apple;
      }
      case 'orange': {
        return state.orange;
      }
      case 'watermelon': {
        return state.watermelon;
      }
      default: {
        return ('Not found');
      }
    }
  };
```

**OBJECT LITERAL**

```
const fruits = (fruit: string): string[] => {
   const fruitCategory = {
     apple: state.apple,
     orange: state.orange,
     watermelon: state.watermelon,
     default: 'Not Found',
  };
  return fruitCategory[fruit] ?? fruitCategory.default;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give your `fruitCategory` object an *index signature* to indicate that it can be *indexed* by any `string` value.

```
const fruits = (fruit: string): string[] => {
  const fruitCategory: Record<string, string[]> = {
     apple: state.apple,
     orange: state.orange,
     watermelon: state.watermelon,
     default: ['Not Found'],
  };
  return fruitCategory[fruit] ?? fruitCategory.default;
}
```

Note that you `default` "branch" should also return a `string[]`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgJwK4EsoRgXhgCkaqALhmgRTAHMBKY08igbQF0sA+GAbwCgYZRJY+NAGEAhlACmFEAgCexAEoTQCACYAeOpQA0JKGUrN22brzOiADhYA2E2lHESAdJZsTtPMzBmjKdvY5OPn4eXjAA7o4IALYS1uD2gZGSMXHgoV6qEnCiSNZEMAwA5AByILAAYiBIYKpFTBkAvgDcnggSUEgIYPDIIo7ScgxCUCwA-GO9BGKSg7JOWTl5UK2NQA)